# SQL joining columns of the same table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I need help on the following SQL query. Let's say we have `table_1` with these columns:

| number | Customer | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 4514 |  |
| 321 |  | 2 |
| 2 | 5321 |  |
| 2 | 5555 |  |

If there's a number in the list column, that indicates that is that there is a list of numbers that should refer to that list. Below is a snapshot of how the final table should look. When there's a null value in the customer field it indicates that there is a list, that list number you can find the customers on that list when the number = the list. I need to change the number to make reference to the number the list belongs to.

| number | Customer | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 4514 |  |
| 321 | 5321 | 2 |
| 321 | 5555 | 2 |

I've tried with different joins but unsuccessful:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM TABLE_1 
     WHERE list IS NOT NULL) AS table_2 ON TABLE_1.list = table_2.list
```

Comment: Looks like a hierarchical table to me. You show that 321 belongs to 2, but could 2 itself belong to another number again? If so, what is your result supposed to look like then?

Comment: List 2 will always belong to the number 321, it's unique in that sense.

Comment: Okay, so no chains then like 321->2->456->12. That makes it easy :-)

Comment: What is your DBMS by the way? You should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Using BigQuery for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that this is guaranteed to be one level only. So you can have 321->2, but not, say, 321->2->1.

Then, well, let's join and show the joined result:

```
select
  coalesce(ref.number, t1.number) as num,
  t1.customer,
  ref.list
from table_1 t1
left outer join table_1 ref on ref.list = t1.number
where t1.list is null;
```

Comment: This produced a combination of all customers; the number should be always 321 and list = 2 when it had 2 as a number

Comment: No, it doesn't combine all customers. It just combines linked customers as in your example. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/eDr_hlsZ. If you have more data and want to restrict this to 321 and/or 2 then add this/these condition(s) to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change the data (DML). Here us an example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_list

CREATE TABLE customer_list (
    number INT,
    Customer INT,
    list INT
);

INSERT INTO customer_list (number, Customer, list)
VALUES
    (321, 4514, NULL),
    (321, NULL, 2),
    (2, 5321, NULL),
    (2, 5555, NULL);

UPDATE A
SET [number] = B.number
   ,[list] = b.list
FROM customer_list A
INNER JOIN customer_list B
    ON A.number = B.list
WHERE B.Customer IS NULL

DELETE FROM customer_list
WHERE Customer IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM customer_list
```

[image]

---

If you need only to get the records:

```
SELECT B.number
      ,A.customer
      ,B.List
FROM customer_list A
INNER JOIN customer_list B
    ON A.number = B.list
WHERE B.Customer IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Hey unfortunately I can't, this is how the table exists in our database and that is just a simplified snippet for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @jontieez You  want just a SELECT query, not UPDATE?

Comment: Select is prefered if I could do an update from a select?